# Why can't i send a MessageConnection message from a Blackberry group address?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, sms, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to send a lot of sms texts all at once, it works fine when i pull the numbers from the contacts themselves, but when i get them from the group  i get an IllegalArgumentException that says "invalid destination address: trailing characters:" followed by the recipient's number.

I get the numbers from the contacts like this:

```
private void addContactGroup(BlackBerryContactGroup group) {
    BlackBerryContact contact;
    for(int i=0;i<group.numContacts();i++) {
        _cntctsNmbrs.addElement(group.getAddress(i).trim());
    }
}
```

And then i send the message:

```
try {               
    _conn = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
    final TextMessage msgOut = (TextMessage)
    _conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE,
        "sms://"+_cntctsNmbrs.elementAt(i)+":0");
msgOut.setPayloadText(frmtdMsg);
_conn.send(msgOut);
} catch (final Exception e) {}
```

I searched all over but couldn't find this error anywhere.

Comment: Is getAddress always returning a phone number? What if the contact is an email address or a PIN number? You're not checking the type of the contact...

Comment: ive simplified the code just to test it with numbers only, and all of the groups i tested it with only had phone numbers entered with them

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that some of the rim oses add invisible control characters to the strings of group's addresses, i just called `stringbuf.deleteCharAt(0)` for each address and it worked out